# Datatables initial rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to inital show up a specified number of rows with Datatables.
For example -> showing row 100-105.

Anyone knowing if it is possible using the options?

Comment: Something wrong with the documentation?

Comment: sorry everthing fine. searched within the examples. docu is alright.
thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://datatables.net/usage/options):

> **`iDisplayLength`** Number of rows to display on a single
>   page when using pagination. If feature enabled (`bLengthChange`) then
>   the end user will be able to over-ride this to a custom setting using
>   a pop-up menu.
>
> **`iDisplayStart`** Define the starting point for data display
>   when using DataTables with pagination. Note that this parameter is the
>   number of records, rather than the page number, so if you have 10
>   records per page and want to start on the third page, it should be
>   "20".

Comment: Agreed. Between using iDisplayStart and iDisplayLength, you should be good to go.